# problem with the application properties settings file when replacing a *.Exe

Tags: c#, xml, properties, settings, exe

When replacing a new copy of my application at the customer, the application properties settings are erased and must be specified again
I searched a lot for a solution and couldn't find it please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Properties.Settings.Default.SettingsUpgradeRequired` variable to check for updates. If there is something new, use `Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade`

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.SettingsUpgradeRequired)
        {
            try
            {
                Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade();
                Properties.Settings.Default.SettingsUpgradeRequired = false;
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {                    
            }
        }
```

Comment: thanks, Where should I use this

Comment: At start of the application

Comment: ok thank you i will try it